# XSLT 1.0 How to use xsl:key with document() function

Tags: document, xslt-1.0, xslkey

I'm trying to use xsl:key to lookup items in an external XML document, using the XSL document() function.  I am able to get the xsl:key part to work if, instead of using document(), I just merge the two XML files (using XmlDocument in C#).  However both XML files are very large, and I'm starting to get "out of memory" errors in some cases.  Also I need to be able to use xls:key, otherwise the process takes hours.

In XSLT 2.0, I believe you can do something like this:

```xsl
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="lookupDoc" select="document('CodeDescriptions.xml')" />
    <xsl:key name="LookupDescriptionByCode" match="Code/@description" use="../@code" />

    <xsl:template match="ItemCode">
        <xsl:call-template name="MakeSpanForCode">
            <xsl:with-param name="code" select="text()" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="MakeSpanForCode">
        <xsl:param name="code" />
        <xsl:element name="span">
            <xsl:attribute name="title">
                <xsl:value-of select="$lookupDoc/key('LookupDescriptionByCode', $code)" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="$code" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How do you accomplish this in XSLT 1.0 though?

Answer (score 13):

You have two possibilities:

#### without key

```xml
<xsl:template name="MakeSpanForCode">
    <xsl:param name="code" />

    <xsl:element name="span">
        <xsl:attribute name="title">
            <xsl:value-of select="$lookupDoc/*/Code[@code = $code]/@description" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="$code" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

#### with key

The key definition applies to all documents, but you need to change the context node before using the key() function:

```xml
<xsl:template name="MakeSpanForCode">
    <xsl:param name="code" />

    <xsl:element name="span">
        <xsl:attribute name="title">
            <!-- trick: change context node to external document -->
            <xsl:for-each select="$lookupDoc">
                <xsl:value-of select="key('LookupDescriptionByCode', $code)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="$code" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Also see two great mailing list answers from [Mike Kay](http://oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200105/msg00546.html) and [Jeni Tennison](http://oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200101/msg00217.html) on this topic